# Dense optical flow between two frames

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to compute dense optical flow using Farneback method and i face following error :  error: (-215) scn == 1 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4) in function ipp_cvtColor

My code :

```
Mat flow, cflow, frame1,frame2;
UMat gray1,gray2, uflow;
namedWindow("flow", 1);


frame1 = imread("./car1.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
frame2 = imread("./car2.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);

cvtColor(frame1, gray1, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cvtColor(frame2, gray2, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);


calcOpticalFlowFarneback(gray2, gray1, uflow, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0);
cvtColor(frame2, cflow, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
uflow.copyTo(flow);
drawOptFlowMap(flow, cflow, 16, 1.5, Scalar(0, 255, 0));
imshow("flow", cflow);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thuis line

```
cvtColor(frame2, cflow, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
```

is probably the culprit.
On a line above you load `frame2` as a color image using `frame2 = imread("./car2.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);` but now you are trying to convert it *from gray* instead, which seems illogical.

Comment: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow This happens now...

Comment: As the error somewhat cryptically tells you, the `Mat` you are passing to `imshow` is empty. I.e. at least one of its dimensions is zero. You should probably look over your matrices and see which one is used where and for what purpose.